# Can graphics drivers cause checkboxes to not show up correctly and make line numbers in gedit disappear?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with the Intel HD4000 graphics and recently my checkboxes have been not been showing the boxes. Only the checkmark shows. Same with many other options like dropdown menus. Today I noticed that the line numbers in gedit would not show up. Could graphics drivers be causing this problem? can I roll back? How can I roll back. I've included an image that shows the problems.[image: Line numbers and boxes gone.]

Comment: I don't think graphics drivers are the cause. It's more likely something else broke. When did you last reboot?

Comment: I last rebooted an hour ago. How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: Did you install anything recently?

Comment: @user170868:  It could indeed be the graphics drivers - we don't want to throw that possibility out right away. Read [this blog post](https://sudodblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/31/ubuntu-tech-snippet-12-fix-the-nvidia-screen-flicker-bug-in-ubuntu/) and try applying that fix and see if it helps.

Comment: @Zacharee1, nothing graphics related. The last program I installed was pdf-merge.

Comment: What about before that? Like I said, I don't think it has to do with graphics.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness that did not help.

Comment: @Zacharee1, I can't recall anything significant. How can I troubleshoot if it's not related to graphics? How can I locate the problem?

Comment: You could try running (with sudo): `apt-get install -f` `dpkg --configure -a` `apt-get check-missing` and some more that I can't remember.

Comment: @Zacharee1, I've an Intel HD4000. Should I revert to Nouveau? Also, I get an error saying `E: Command line option --configure is not understood
` when I run the command

Comment: Try it. It's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @Zacharee1 it didn't work. I have no clue what's going on. Also the command you gave didn't work. See me previous comment for the error that showed up.

Comment: @user170868 You should run `sudo apt-get install -f`, then `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, *then*, `sudo apt-get check-missing`. Zacharee formatted his comment badly.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness thanks! That makes a lot more sense now

Comment: @user170868 np ;) Sorry my comment didn't help :( Did you reboot after following those instructions?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness, I did reboot. The command Zacharee gave didn't return any missing packages either. I'm at a total loss. Another issue is that the firefox and thunderbird icons turn into gray boxes with question marks.

Answer (score 0):

**First off**

Yes, your graphics card, could possibly be using a wrong or corrupted driver that makes it render some GUI elements incorrectly. It's recommended that you reinstall the drivers. You should have begun the post with your specs, but never mind. I guess you're using a Nvidia card.

**Uninstalling**

The first thing you need to do is to uninstall the driver you're currently using (if the re-installation didn't work). How to do that depends on the method you installed the driver. If you installed it using Nvidia's Unix/Linux GNU script provided on their website, then launch that script again with the :

> --uninstall

flag to it, at the end. If you installed it using the ppa/terminal/deb file, type in this:

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
>
> (For apt-fast users: sudo apt-fast purge nvidia*)

If you didn't install any drivers at all, Google how to disable nouveau driver.

**Installing, well... Again**

Now you have to install the correct packages for the Nvidia card, that i *assume*, you're using. With the graphical glitches, you've been having, I suggest you to use the *stable* Nvidia drivers. 
*I don't recommend any beta drivers.*

To install the drivers type in:

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
>
> (For apt-fast users: sudo apt-fast install nvidia-current)

and the installation shall begin, if you don't have any repo-related problems.

**Finalizing**

When the drivers have finished installing (correct me if I'm wrong), all you have to do is reboot your system, and hope the glitches are gone. If everything is still like it was... The last thing I can suggest you is googling on "How to reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` package". If that still doesn't help, well another theme or a full reinstall would be the only (non-elegant) solutions

***If i helped, a vote up would be appreciated***

EDIT: Just read the comments, and noticed you're using Intel HD4000. I will leave the post, maybe someone else will have use of it.

Comment: No solutions for the Intel HD4000? I really want to avoid reinstalling.